# Reaction of Diols with HX hydrohalic acids, Competing SN2 Reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

Suppose 1,5-pentanediol were exposed to something like hydroiodic acid. Would the alkoxonium end of the diol be exposed to a nucleophilic attack by the remaining hydroxide at the other end for a ring formation? Or would the newly-free iodide ion be more competitive for substitution? Thanks!

edit: It was pointed out to me "newly-free iodide" was quite confusing. I meant it as though HI dissociated, the Hydrogen ion attacked one end of the diol, and the iodide from the HI being "newly-free". Now that one end of the diol has a good leaving group (H2O), is it more susceptible to be attacked by the iodide, or by the other end (OH) of the diol.

Comment: Unclear as to the meaning of "newly-free iodide". Did you mean 5-iod0pentane-1-ol? Depending on conditions, the cyclic ether (tetrahydropyran) would be susceptible to HI cleavage with formation of 1,5-diiodopentane.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help/feedback! I did my best to clarify in the edit.

Comment: Basically, you’re asking whether the product will be 1,5-diiodopentane or tetrahydropyrane (oxane), aren’t you?

Answer (score 3):

Bob:
Here is the likely process. The alcohol **1** is protonated to provide intermediate **2** which undergoes S<sub>N</sub>2 displacement. The closure of **3** to  tetrahydropyran **6** is unlikely under the reaction conditions. Rather a second displacement via **4** would lead to diiodide **5**. If the tetrahydropyran did form, ethers are cleaved by HI. The conversion of **3** to **6** is normally accomplished in the presence of base (NaH/THF).

[image]